# TCPIP stream can read

Tags: tcp

I am sending and recieving messages from a unix server, all is fine and working as intended...except when I dont get a response from the server, I can confirm the server did get my message, but for whatever reason on their end they dont respond.
I am using the below code on my read, it gets to numberOfBytesRead = and hangs up my app.

```
If serverStream.CanRead Then

                    Dim myReadBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(1024) {}

                    Dim myCompleteMessage As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

                    Dim numberOfBytesRead As Integer = 0



                    Do

                        numberOfBytesRead = serverStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length)

                        If My.Settings.initCompassLive Then

                            myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead))

                        Else

                            myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 2, numberOfBytesRead))

                        End If

                    Loop While serverStream.DataAvailable

                     ' MsgBox("You received the following message : " + myCompleteMessage.ToString)

                    returndata = myCompleteMessage.ToString

                Else

                    MsgBox("Aauth Request Failed: " & returndata)

                    Exit Sub

                End If
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean hang (waits indefinitely) or hang up (abruptly closes). In blocking i/o, the read could hang forever if the server acks data sent but doesn't send back any new data. It could also cause an error to be returned by the read if it closes the connection passively by not acknowledging the data sent or sending a reset.

Comment: Sorry, waits indefinitely, I know why I dont get a response, nothing I can do about it, I just need to handle not getting anything back at all rather than just waiting for a response that wont come.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed a serverStream.ReadTimeOut = bla bla bla

TYVM
MW